# Generate POST request in iOS using AFNetworking

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, fedena

I was asked to build an iOS app based on Fedena (School management system). Their API sample codes are in HTML-JS or RUBY. What I have to do is to pass the arguments (token, URI, etc..) programatically, and upon sending them, the request will return an XML file which I can then parse and view in a tableView.

1. How can I pass parameters by code, using AFNetworking?
2. How can I fetch the XML file?

This is an example of the API code provided:

```
<html>
  <head>
    xhr.open('GET', fedena_server+"/api/users/"+username);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token token="'+token+'"');
    xhr.send();
    ......
```

Comment: You shouldn't consider sending them in HTML/JS.
If you don't have experience using a REST API, check out https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
The API call you need is clear from the code you shared, you have to send a Get request and add an HTTPHeaderField for the authentication.
Let me know if you need further help

Comment: @JadFeitrouni Could you please give an example, regarding my code? Would be very thankful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will have to add AFNetworking to your project. The easiest way to do so is using pods info can be found here : https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

the following code will fetch the response for the mentioned API call:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/users/%@",fedenaServer,username];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token token=%@",token];
[manager.requestSerializer token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorisation"];
[manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // your code to parse the response
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

You'll have to do a bit of research for the whole thing to work, like parsing the XML response
Giving you more than that would be doing the job for you :P
Hope it helps.

Comment: Heheh thanks a lot. I tried it and it worked. Parsing the XML file is easy now. Thank ya :)

Comment: How can we add search params in GET request as per fedena docs? What is the format?